# Is it possible to install Windows on a hard drive on one computer, then activate it on another?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, license-key, transfer

To clarify, I have a machine which I generally use Linux on; but I develop for multiple platforms and will eventually need to test on Windows 10/11. This is an amazing machine but installation of Windows can take a while, as I recall, and I would prefer to either be programming on it, watching something on Netflix, or processing/analyzing with it if I have the option.

I have an older, but not old, machine on my right, which has six open drive bays. I know that registration of Windows is keyed to the hardware profile, so I'm wondering; can I install Windows on a hard drive while it's in that machine, remove it, install the drive in this one, and then simply activate it on the final machine? Will that work, or am I missing something and it will care what hardware it was installed on, too?

Comment: Why not use a virtual machine?

Comment: I do use a virtual machine! However, VMs generally have indirect access to graphics cards, which is very relevant to the work I do. So, I like to have a standalone instance available, all the same.

Comment: You can use Windows 10 indefinitely with minimal restrictions (essentially some minor annoyances regarding customization). There is no real need to activate it.

Comment: "Can I install Windows on a hard drive while it's in that machine, remove it, install the drive in this one, and then simply activate it on the final machine?" - It might but it likely won't.  You will probably get drivers issues out of the box.  It shouldn't take more than 20 minutes to install Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I used to install Windows 8, later W10, for a living, along with computer repair, in my last job. I could generally have it done in ten minutes. It's not so much the time, but the lead-in and lead-out, that bothers me--with Mint, you can go weeks without a restart. However, I'll need to shut down every multimedia, software, and web app I'm using, and remember, half an hour later, how to boot them all back. It's a real problem. So, I'm putting my old machine to use. We'll see if I have driver issues and how much of a problem they are to fix, though.

Comment: @MichaelMacha - I haven’t restarted my machine in 3 weeks. What does the uptime of a Windows machine have to do with anything? Windows 10 restores the state of compatible applications when restarted. Sounds like your making the process harder then it needs to be.  I have work systems that have been up for a year.

Comment: @Ramhound That's a little off-topic, I generally presume that SO users have a legitimate reason for whatever they're trying to do, and often a reason that may not be my business. Let's get back to the basic discussion of whether Win10 will allow installation on one machine and activation on the other.

Comment: @MichaelMacha - In my experience, you will not have success, unless you use [sysprep](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/sysprep--generalize--a-windows-installation?view=windows-11) which is a pain to use even for an experienced administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is in fact tied to hardware, so if you are asking if you can install Windows 10 on one computer, pull the drive and have it be seen as a licensed copy on the other machine, the basic answer is "no." (You *can* change the license to a valid one at this point though.)

If, however, you are asking "can I install to a drive, move that drive to another machine, and then activate/license windows 10 on the new hardware" then the answer is "yes."

You can add a clean drive as a secondary drive; mount an ISO/image of windows-10 setup disc along with the `dism` tool (and `diskpart` etc) to setup an "out of box experience" Windows 10 install on that secondary drive; make it bootable; then drop it into a new computer. You can then add a valid retail license after/during the OOBE first boot.

You can then image the drive itself and use that as a snapshot image to revert to a vanilla system.

The dism part looks something like this:

```
--mount the ISO file with drive letter {ISO}
-- {NEW_OS} refers to drive letter of the secondary drive we are installing windows to.

--find appropriate OS image index on the ISO. This will be the OS version you want ( {INDEX#} ) :
dism /Get-ImageInfo /ImageFile:{ISO}:\sources\install.wim

--identify desired index and use for the following command (installs the OS to new disk):
dism /Apply-Image /ImageFile:{ISO}:\sources\install.wim /Index:{INDEX#} /ApplyDir:{NEW_OS}:\
```

Note the index is the license level that matches your license (e.g. home/pro) so you need to query that. The partitioning and bootable part varies (i.e GPT or not GPT).

There are many walk-throughs of this process, and the `diskpart` commands are "dangerous enough" for me to not ad-lib. Maybe search for "dism install windows-10 apply-image".

Comment: Michael, I used EaseUS Partition Master to have a Windows 10 system on a second hard disk without reinstalling Windows OS. Check here https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-software/install-windows-10-on-second-hard-drive.html#part1